# Proper Mongo usage in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

How do I create a proper mongo based application in Go using the official driver`(go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo)`? I have a `MongoConnect()` and `MongoDisconnect(client)` function to create a connection and delete it. But, it's not too efficient and starts leaking FD as the app has got around 40 functions and finding all the missed `MongoDisconnect()` becomes hectic.

The current `MongoConnect` and `MongoDisconnect` are as follows.

```golang
func MongoConnect() (*mongo.Client, error) {
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI("mongodb://localhost:27017")
    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.TODO(), clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        Logger(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    err = client.Ping(context.TODO(), nil)
    if err != nil {
        Logger(err)
        return nil, err
    }
    return client, err
}
```

```golang
func MongoDisconnect(client *mongo.Client) {
    _ = client.Disconnect(context.TODO())
}
```

I am looking for a method that would still use `MongoConnect()` to create connections and would automatically kill the client without the usage of `MongoDisconnect()`.

PS. Other methods that are better than the above requirement are also welcome

Comment: You should create a pool and implement usage of Connect/ Disconnect and provide API for pool usage; Also you can have a timeout if connection is not closed/used it will automatically be closed.

Comment: You should create a single client on app start, and only close it on app shutdown. Reuse it wherever you need, it's safe for concurrent use and maintains an internal connection pool.

Comment: Hey guys. Do you happen to have any example code that I could refer to?

Comment: @ShubhamSrivastava the driver already handles connection pooling, writing your own on top of it would be redundant.

Comment: Your issue of "starts leaking FD if the traffic is high" is unlikely to have anything to do with the connect/disconnect code shown; it's going to be to do with the code that's actually using MongoDB, e.g. not closing cursors when you're done with them.

Comment: Hi @Adrian, you are absolutely right. The FD leak is due to devs missing `MongoDisconnect`. We added the disconnect function a bit late, and with around 30-40 functions using the `MongoConnect()` and `MongoDisconnect()` in the app, it kinda became hectic to corner the missing cases. Thus, I'm asking if there's any other efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there is an 'efficient' way to fix the underlying issue, you probably will need to look at all the places where you've called `MongoConnect()` and ensure you have a corresponding `MongoDisconnect()`.

In saying that, what you might want to look at is implemententing the right pattern for connecting to databases.

Generally speaking, if your database driver takes care of managing connections for you then you should create the connection once and just pass it around as needed.

You could also defer the closing of that connection to a go routine which would close it once it was no longer needed (when you're application is shutting down).

Here is a code snippet of how this is implemented:

```
// =========================================================================
// Start Database

log.Println("main: Initializing database support")

db, err := database.Open(database.Config{
    User:       cfg.DB.User,
    Password:   cfg.DB.Password,
    Host:       cfg.DB.Host,
    Name:       cfg.DB.Name,
    DisableTLS: cfg.DB.DisableTLS,
})
if err != nil {
    return errors.Wrap(err, "connecting to db")
}
defer func() {
    log.Printf("main: Database Stopping : %s", cfg.DB.Host)
    db.Close()
}()
```

I didn't write this code and its part of a larger project scaffold which has some other nice patterns for web applications.

[Ultimate service](https://github.com/ardanlabs/service/blob/master/app/sales-api/main.go)